# Microsoft Access 2003 VBA - Login Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

This is my first attempt to create a login form. I've read up a few forums about it and tried them myself. However, I've encountered the error when trying out the form.

"Run time error '2001': You canceled the previous operation."

Here's my code! The error highlighted is the DLOOKUP statement. When I move my cursor to LanID, it appears to be 0. (I guess it got something to do with it?)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private intLoginAttempts As Integer

Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
'Check mandatory fields
If IsNull(Me.txtLanID) Or Me.txtLanID = "" Then
   MsgBox "Lan ID is required.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
   Me.txtLanID.SetFocus
   Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Or Me.txtPassword = "" Then
   MsgBox "Password is required.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
   Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
   Exit Sub
End If

'Compare input password and database password
If Me.txtLanID <> "" Then
   If Me.txtPassword = DLookup("Password", "tblUser", "[LanID]=" & Me.txtLanID) Then
      LanID = Me.txtLanID

      'Close Login Page
      DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmUserLogin", acSaveNo

      'Check whether user is an admin
      If Me.txtAdmin = DLookup("Administrator", "tblUser", "[LanID]=" & Me.txtLanID) Then
         If Me.txtAdmin = -1 Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMenu"
            Else
               DoCmd.OpenForm "frmBack"
         End If
      End If

   Else
      MsgBox "Invalid Password. Try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
      Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
   End If
End If

'If user enters incorrect password 3 times
intLoginAttempts = intLoginAttempts + 1
If intLoginAttempts = 3 Then
   MsgBox "You do not have access to the database. Please contact system administrator.", vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
   Application.Quit
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `tblUser.LanID` is text data type, enclose `Me.txtLanID` in quotes to avoid an error with your `DLookup()` expression.  (You don't need `.Value` there because it's the default property.)

```vba
DLookup("Password", "tblUser", "[LanID]='" & Me.txtLanID & "'")
```

If that was not the explanation, test your `DLookup()` expression in the Immediate window (go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) to see whether it throws an error or what value it does return.

Note, when you test `DLookup()` in the Immediate window, use the current value of `Me.txtLanID`.  For example, if `Me.txtLanID` contains the text "*foo*", test it like this ...

```vba
? DLookup("Password", "tblUser", "[LanID]='foo'")
```

Comment: Sounds like you tried to use `Me.txtLanID` in the Immediate window.  Sorry, I should have anticipated that mistake.  See updated answer.

Comment: oh! Thanks for your patience! I've tried it, the password appears after the DLookup statement.

Comment: Rats!  I may be stumped.  You didn't show us an `End Sub` at the end of `cmdLogin_Click()`.  Does the full procedure actually include `End Sub`?  Do you have `Option Explicit` in the form module's Declarations section and have you run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu without turning up any compile errors?

Comment: No compilation error...I've attached the full coding, take a look. Thanks again!

Comment: What is the data type of `tblUser.LanID`?

Comment: Data type 'TEXT' is set to LanID. It's a primary key.

Comment: An hour ago I warned you "*If tblUser.LanID is text data type, enclose Me.txtLanID in quotes to avoid an error with your DLookup() expression*".  You have not included those quotes in your code sample.

Comment: OH MY GOD! I must be blind... Thanks a lot! I've solved it! You're awesome! I've also change the data type of LANID (which i created in a module) to variant. After I add in the quotes, type mismatch appears, since before i declare LanID as Long.